# Big-O Notation, Find the Smallest

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

Give the smallest O() estimate you can for the following functions:

```
4n2 + 5n – 8 = O(...)


log(n)2 + n = O(...)
```

If you guys can, explain the answer rather than giving it to me. A question like this will be on my mid-term and I want to understand this.

Thanks

Comment: what does this question have to do with java?

Comment: Should the 2 be interpreted as squared?

Comment: SO answers homework questions too? Really?

Comment: @ashes, Yes, 9042 homework questions so far: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework

Answer (score 4):

When having sums of terms you should think of it as "does one term subsume another?". So which one of 4n<sup>2</sup>, 5n and 8 subsumes the others?

The second one: log(n)<sup>2</sup>+n  can be rewritten using logarithmic laws: 2*log(n)+n. Constants don't matter, so basically you have to figure out which one subsumes the other when comparing *log(n)* and *n*. I'm sure you know the answer here ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Big-O notation is ordered in growing complexity as described here on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation, they have a nice table showing an ordered list of growing complexities, if you had any further questions about it/were unsure about something.

Answer (score 0):

The notation is wrong. A function is not **equals** O class, a function is **an element** of O class

Answer (score 0):

When summing equations : choose the "heaviest" one. (Largest in asymptotic order).

If you like to checkout how it works with algebra, or some [CAS support, checkout this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882915/asymptotic-complexity-of-logarithms-and-powers/8790940#8790940).